# Does MIDP 2.0 say that this phone has at least GPRS connectivity?

Tags: java-me, gprs, midp-2.0, mmapi

Does MIDP 2.0 say that this phone has at least GPRS capability?

I need to come up with a list of phones which has MIDP 2.0, and GPRS capability.

Comment: you mean support of GPRS or live connectivity you want to check ?

Comment: yes support of GPRS and not live connectivity, I have edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

MIDP gives a Java based interface, architecture, and library, for high level programming of the phone. It does not say anything about the physical capabilities of the underlying system. Technically, the device you're programming against is not even guaranteed to be a phone - any device could decide to implement the MIDP, as long as it has any kind of two-way, wireless, possibly intermittent, network connection.

You can check the full details of the spec here if you want:

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_JCP-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SimpleBundleDownload

The suggested hardware requirements for devices are on pages 7-8. Note the use of the word "SHOULD" - devices might not actually have all or even any of these properties.

Answer (score -1):

The GPRS is based on various service provider such as airtel,vodafone.

Comment: actualy what question asks is whether phone will support GPRS functionality (assuming service provider gives the connection)